# New version of sorl-thumbnail , how show thumb in django admin?

Tags: django, django-admin, sorl-thumbnail

im using the new version of Sorl-thumbnail, but i cant show thumbs in django admin...

how ill use get_thumbnail() ?, just i can see the "cache" url of the images...

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

i did it

```
from sorl.thumbnail import get_thumbnail
def thumb(self):
        if self.imagen:
            t = get_thumbnail(self.imagen,"50x50",crop='center', quality=99)
            return u'<img src="%s" />' % t.url            
        else:
            return u"None"
    thumb.short_description = 'Foto'
    thumb.allow_tags = True
```

Answer (score 3):

It's a new version with beter docs too! :) http://thumbnail.sorl.net/examples.html#admin-examples (This is for displaying images in forms, not in listing).